# How can i clear the Directory dropdown for Find in Files?

Tags: notepad++

I created an Autoit Script to assist me in my work by running a string in Notepad++'s File in Files against multiple directories.

during testing however it did enter some bugged text in some fields. while most are just text boxes and thus not a problem the **Directory:** dropdown/text box has saved some of these bugged entries in the dropdown like

> BalanceRuleCatCodesD:_Work\Automation\ks\Azure\rptObjectAnalysis

aside from the start of that the `\ks\` part is actually missing a chunk of the string that was supposed to be inputted

I want to know how i can clear the Directory dropdown for Find in Files without needing to uninstall and reinstall it

Answer (score -1):

Open `config.xml` file (it is in the same directory as file which opens on menu **Settings** > **Edit Popup ContextMenu**) and delete all unnecessary `Path` entries, then save and restart Notepad++.

The following image shows where five of them near the beginning of the file:

[image]

- you are editing the config of the editor itself so **make sure that** (if this is not obvious)

  1. you exited the Notepad++ ***before*** editing its config file
  2. you are editing the file in some ***different*** editor
  3. you start Notepad++ only after you ***saved*** the updated config

Comment: did you try? doesn't work

Comment: @qadenza – upon your comment I gave it a retry. I saw it works 100% for me even in the latest Notepad++ v7.9. Make sure you used the correct path to the config file (answer updated). And do not attempt to edit the config in the Notepad++ to which it belongs :)